# How much data can craft()->cache hold?

Tags: plugin-development, cache

How much data can I push into one craft()->cache key?

Let's say I have a json string that's reaaaallly long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`craft()->cache` can point to different places, depending on what the [cacheMethod](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) config setting is set to.

By default, it's set to `file`, which means that your cache will be saved to the file system in the `craft/runtime/storage/cache` folder.

So you can pretty much save as much there as you have disk space available.

Just keep in mind, if you're saving something that's 500MB worth of text, PHP is roughly going need 500MB worth of extra memory to be able to read and write that data.

Comment: Thank you Brad. Then I know what's going on. I thought it was stored in the DB - that's why I asked :)